# Ansible: How to parse looped registered variable?

Tags: json, linux, ansible

I'm working on a playbook that needs to make some webrequests which is getting back JSON output. This works awesome for single requests, but I need to loop through a list to get a list of docker images.

Here is what I got so far:

```
- name: get all repositories from project
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ harbor_url }}/api/v2.0/projects/{{ harbor_project }}/repositories?page=1&page_size=50"
        return_content: yes
        validate_certs: no
        url_username: "{{ username }}"
        url_password: "{{ password }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
      register: repositories

    - name: temp to variable
      set_fact:
        repo_list_tmp: "{{ repositories.json | json_query('[*].name') | list }}"


    - name: set repos as a list and trim names
      set_fact:
        repo_list: "{{ repo_list|default([]) + [ item.split(seperator)[1] ] }}"
      loop: "{{ repo_list_tmp }}"

    - name: get all images from a project
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ harbor_url }}/api/v2.0/projects/{{ harbor_project }}/repositories/{{ item }}/artifacts?page=1&page_size=50&with_tag=true&with_label=false&with_scan_overview=false&with_signature=false&with_immutable_status=false"
        return_content: yes
        validate_certs: no
        url_username: "{{ username }}"
        url_password: "{{ password }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
      loop: "{{ repo_list }}"
      register: images
```

The last task loops through the repo_list variable and register it's output to "images", as Ansible works the register in a loop always creates a dictionary and here's the proble, I got no clue on how to get specific values with a json query or something else out of it.

As the output is too big for stackoverflow I added it to a pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/GzQJfBUL

This is the whole output from the URI task. What I need is to extract the following:

item (in this example myimage or myotherimage) -> tags -> name

For example, inside the output is this entry:

```
                        "tags": [
                            {
                                "artifact_id": 4776,
                                "id": 2373,
                                "immutable": false,
                                "name": "MYTAG_ELASTICSEARCH",
                                "pull_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                "push_time": "2021-09-21T11:33:47.687Z",
                                "repository_id": 303,
                                "signed": false
                            }
```

How do I extract values from a looped registerd value?

Thank you

Dan

Comment: does `{{ images | json_query('results[*].json[*].tags[*].name') | flatten }}` do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mdaniel's comment below the first post, this did the trick:

```
{{ images | json_query('results[*].json[*].tags[*].name') | flatten }}
```

Thank you!